# SPARQL Query - Get Links

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I want to run a specific query at the LMDB SPARQL-Endpoint ( http://data.linkedmdb.org/snorql/ ). For some reason I can't get the link of movie that is returned.

My Query:

```
SELECT ?aName ?mName ?link ?aLink ?mLink 
      WHERE {
            ?link <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/performance_character> 'Adam Faulkner' .
            ?link <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/performance_actor> ?aName .
            ?link <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/performance_film> ?mName . 
            ?aLink <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/actor_name> ?aName .
            }
```

I have tried `?mLink <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/filmid> ?mName` like the last line of the query because this way I got the `?aLink` but for some reason it doesn't work this way. I've also tried with `dc:title ?mName` and then trying to get the link from that but it didn't work either. Has anybody some idea how to deal with this problem ?

Comment: Don't forget what I told you last time - the data is heavily outdated...

Comment: @AKSW I know but I don't know how to set up my own SPARQL-Endpoint or where can I find another SPARQL-Endpoint which has acual data. Can you recommend a tutorial or something like this where I can see how to set up my own triple store and access it from JS scripts ?

Comment: There is no similar dataset. The problem is not the tripe store but that the dataset itself is outdated. You'd have to generate the latest dataset first, but therefore I guess you have to adapt the code from [here](https://github.com/snrlx/IMDb-To-RDF-Parser) first - or maybe it still works, but the IMDB schema might have been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `performance_film` references to a string not a URI, it is not possible for you find the `filmid` information from there. So you should traverse back for the movie link:

```
SELECT ?aName ?mName ?link ?aLink ?m WHERE {
 ?link <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/performance_character> 'Adam Faulkner' .
 ?link <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/performance_actor> ?aName .
 ?link <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/performance_film> ?mName . 
 ?aLink <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/actor_name> ?aName .
 ?m <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/performance> ?link .
 ?m <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/filmid> ?id.
}
```

Comment: Yes this query works , but there's a little problem there. Because we get `?aLink` and `?mLink` from `?link` every result is printed out at  least 2 times. I don't know if you know what I mean: try to change `'Adam Faulker'` with `'Darth Vader'` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: No actually there is no problem there, only issue is what you call '?mlink' is related with both filmid and actorid. I assume that you want only the movie id so I update my answer such but I would suggest you to read the data that you would like to query and add the information that you would like -in that case movie information.

Comment: The updated answer doesn't work. Do you have any idea how to to get the movieID some other way ?

Comment: @user7306111 Nice! It works exactly the way I wanted it to be! I just do n't understand why and I even tried something like the last line you added and didn't seem to work. Anyways Thank you a lot ! Best answer!